# Pass a function within component returning specify content

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have multiple pages in my site.

I created a component for content section containing text and images. For each page, I have created a class to show/hide on the corresponding page. Now the problem is that the page loading is very slow due to large contents. Is there any way to load only the content required for the page. I don't wish to hide/show because that is still rendered in the DOM making the site slow.

something like below

```
//in page1.js
<ContentComponent content="page1"/> 
//in page2.js
<ContentComponent content="page2"/> 

//component
const ContentComponent =() => {
 return(
     page1= { 
        <div>content for page 1</div>
     }
     page2= { 
        <div>content for page 2</div>
     }
 )
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to do:

```js
// ContentComponent.jsx
const ContentComponent =(props) => {
 if (!props.children) {
   return null;
 }

 return <div style={/* some styles for content */}>{props.children}<div>;
}
```

```js
// page1.jsx
...
return (
  <div>
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
  <ContentComponent>
     <div>content for page 1</div>
  </ContentComponent>
  </div>
);
```

```js
// page2.jsx
...
return (
  <div>
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
  <ContentComponent>
     <div>content for page 2</div>
  </ContentComponent>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access through props- like this using destructuring.

```
//in page1.js
<ContentComponent content1="page1"/> 
//in page2.js
<ContentComponent content2="page2"/> 

//component
const ContentComponent =({content1, content2}) => {
 return(
     <>
      <h3>{content1}</h3>
      <h3>{content2}</h3>
     </>
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the share. In page1, I guess the contents of page2 will also be rendered in the DOM. What's the way to load only the content of the required page only